# Facing issue during changing the height depending on the screen size in angular6

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular, bootstrap-4

I am using HostListener for changing the height depending on the screen size this is working but during the load of the page the "event.target.innerHeight" give undefined later i will get the value as i change the browser height, so i have initialize the value. Initially if the user browse on a big screen the value will not change

```
 Here is the code

  myInnerHeight = 524;         //Laptop screen
  mypaletteHeight = 471;       //Laptop screen

@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event) {
    if (event.target.innerHeight > 680) {
     this.myInnerHeight = 727;     //bigger screen
     this.mypaletteHeight = 674;    //bigger screen
    } else {
      this.myInnerHeight = 524;      //Laptop screen
      this.mypaletteHeight = 471;    //Laptop screen
    }
  }

HTML

<div class="card h-100" [style.min-height.px]="myInnerHeight" >
....
     <div class="sub2" id="sub2" [style.height.px] = "mypaletteHeight">
     .
     .
      </div>
</div>
```

I am using Angular 6 and bootstrap 4.

how to get the value of the screen size on the load of the page.Please help me with this issue

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve? Is this not something that could be achieved with CSS?

Comment: Media query FTW!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try window.screen.height & window.screen.width

To get the document client width & Height, document.documentElement.clientWidth & document.documentElement.clientHeight